# Firefox is dropping packets when downloading large files then stops downloading

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, firefox, internet

Firefox is dropping packets when downloading large files then it stops downloading the file. I'm using Windows 10 20H2

Below is what I've already tried

- Using Windows Update
- Updating all the programs in the Microsoft Store
- Updating my drivers
- Running [netcut](https://arcai.com/) (to prevent others on the same wifi network from disconnecting me)
- Using sfc and dism scans
- Using chkdsk scans
- Having the correct amount set for virtual memory
- Running Firefox as administrator
- Making sure that under Power Management my network adapter doesn't switch off to save power
- Under Power Plan settings making sure my hard drive doesn't switch off to save power
- Changing my DNS servers to [1.1.1.1 cloudflare](http://1.1.1.1/dns/)
- Clearing my DNS cache in Firefox under about:networking
- Deleting my cookies in firefox
- Checking my ping on the command line using the "ping google.com" command. No packets are dropped there.
- Clearing the DNS cache in windows using various ipconfig and netsh commands on the command line
- Using a VPN

Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to try without VPN and then with Chromium Edge to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: "Large Files" .. is in the eye of the beholder.  It would help to know if you are talking about 5GB? 1TB?  How big is big?

Comment: The file is 3GB

Comment: How did you determine that Firefox is dropping packets?

Comment: I've not used a packet sniffing software like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Because the download suddenly stops halfway.

Comment: How have you determined if's an issue caused by **Firefox**, *per se*? Have you tried the obvious, i.e. using Windows *Edge* browser, or a third-party tool, such as *Free Download Manager*, https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/ ?

Comment: It happens in Microsoft Edge as well. Download managers are designed to automatically resume prematurely stopped downloads, so it ignores and hides the problem .

Comment: You could do one more experiment, using a Live Linux CD/USB to check whether it's affected, too. Also, do you have other computers/devices you could try with on the same connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was caused by using a public wifi hotspot and someone else who's connected to it doing some sort of attack. It could be a man in the middle (MITM) or [ARP spoofing attack](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/protect-your-computer-against-arp-poison-attack-netcut/). Because when I tried to access gmail with the VPN off I got an error but there was no error when I turned it on. Data that is transmitted through a public wifi hotspot travels through the air unencrypted, which is why TLS (or https://) that shows the secure padlock in the web browser is important,

[image: firefox the connection has timed out]